# How to put dot after the last letter of a functioin

Tags: python, function

i have to make a function that will return  the first letters of its word and make it upper case with a dot adter the letter.
 exable:
user input"this is sunday"
and the function will make it look like this
"T. I. S."

i have made it until the point i have to use the last dot.

```
def initials(text):
    words = text.split()

    letters = [word[0] for word in words]

    return  ". ".join(letters).upper()


print(initials("this is sunday"))`
```

i need some help with the last dot.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Won't a comprehension be easier?

```
>>> sentence = "this is Sunday"
>>> '.'.join(word[0].upper() for word in sentence.split()) + '.'
'T.I.S.'
```

Note that it doesn't handle cases like punctuations in a sentence. If you had one in your sentence, you need a specific rule for that, like stripping them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a dot after every letter, go ahead and put it after every letter, right when you extract that letter!
Consider:

```py
def initials(text):
  words = text.split()
  letters = [word[0].upper() + '.' for word in words]  # Here.
  return  "".join(letters)
```